# Kronecker product over the rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, kronecker-product

So I have these two dataframes and I would like to get a new dataframe which consists of the kronecker product of the rows of the two dataframes. What is the correct way to this?

As an example:
DataFrame1

```
   c1   c2
0  10  100
1  11  110
2  12  120
```

and
DataFrame2

```
   a1   a2
0  5    7
1  1   10
2  2   4
```

Then I would like to have the following matrix:

```
   c1a1   c1a2   c2a1   c2a2
0  50     70     500    700
1  11     110    110    1100
2  24     48     240    480
```

I hope my question is clear.

PS. I saw this question was posted here [kronecker product pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812059/kronecker-product-pandas-dataframes). However, the answer given is not the correct answer (I believe to mine and the original question, but definitely not to mine). The answer there gives a Kronecker product of both dataframes, but I only want it over the rows.

Comment: @strategy32 I had added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71968722/16343464) specially for your case in the duplicate (product on a single axis). I think you haven't seen it. I added it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71974815/16343464) as well now. It is more efficient than the chosen answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), convert both columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and multiple Dataframe, last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
c = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1, df2])
df = df1.reindex(c, axis=1, level=0).mul(df2.reindex(c, axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
print (df)
   c1a1  c1a2  c2a1  c2a2
0    50    70   500   700
1    11   110   110  1100
2    24    48   240   480
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy` for efficiency:

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.einsum('nk,nl->nkl', df1, df2).reshape(df1.shape[0], -1),
             columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1, df2]).map(''.join)
            )
```

Output:

```
   c1a1  c1a2  c2a1  c2a2
0    50    70   500   700
1    11   110   110  1100
2    24    48   240   480
```